# Is there any alternative of JIB for golang project, which creates the docker image withour using dockerfile

Tags: go, docker-image, jib, cloudbuild.yaml

I want to create the docker image of golang project using cloud build.yaml but without using dockerfile.
Is there any tool available for golang which is alternative of JIB which creates the docker image without using dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the CNCF project : https://buildpacks.io/

The **buildpack** is similar to JIB mostly.

Here dropping Github link for **GO** **buildpack** : https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/go

Comment: Google Ko does this work but steps are not clear, how to do that.

Comment: https://github.com/ko-build/ko/blob/main/README.md how to build image : https://github.com/ko-build/ko/blob/main/README.md

Comment: suggested the alternative tools as requested if you are facing any specific issue feel free to share mode details.

Comment: I am trying to use the ko image in my cloudbuild.yaml which is : 'gcr.io/distroless/static:nonroot' so I dont have to do any installations and all, but I am getting issue which says: "gcr.io/distroless/static:nonroot" failed: starting step container failed: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task:

Comment: would it be possible for you to create new question and update above one ? it would helpful and other also might would be able get context and idea, if possible please create new question with cloudbuild.yaml file data. it's confusing single line not sure what you are passing as argument to that image.

Comment: I have already created a new question. Here is the url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73810525/how-to-build-and-push-go-image-using-google-kocould-you-tell-me-the-steps-for-c

Comment: feel free to update the status of this question if above answer resolve your problem.